# Evaluating a complex integral using Cauchys Integral Formula

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I need to evaluate the following complex integral:

$ \int_{\phi}\frac{z^3}{z^2+i} dz$

where $\phi$ is the circle centered at $0$ with radius $2$

I know that there is a singularity at $z = \frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}$ (though I can verify this, I couldn't get this result myself either), but this singularity is inside the region so the answer is not $0$

I've considered using Cauchy's Integral Formula.

But I'm having trouble writing $\frac{z^3}{z^2+i}$ in the form $\frac{f(z)}{z-a}$

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: To find the singularities set the denominator of the integrand to zero and solve for z. In fact the denominator has two simple zeros, both of which are inside $\phi $. Check that they are not cancelled by any zeros of the numerator. You could use the Residue Theorem from here on.

Comment: I haven't actually used the Residue theorem, can I approach it using Cauchy's integral formula or some other method?

Comment: The residue theorem can be viewed as a generalisation of Cauchy's Integral formula. Since you have more than one isolated singularity inside your contour, the hypothesis of Cauchy's Integral Formula, as it is usually stated, does not apply.

Comment: You can massage your integral in various ways to get something you can apply the integral formula to. You can substitute $z^2 = w$. Or you can pick your favourite square root $\zeta$ of $-i$, and write the denominator as $z^2 - \zeta^2 = (z-\zeta)(z+\zeta)$, then perform a partial fraction decomposition and apply the integral formula to each term separately.